# ASP .NET Multiple Custom Validators on a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, custom-validators

Can you have more than one CustomValidator on a single page?

I have two separate CustomValidators with two separate controls on one page.  Both ServerValidateEventHandlers are setup for each control.

The issue is that it only fires on the first event handler twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple CustomValidators. Are you sure that the custom validators are using different OnServerValidate methods and they aren't both pointing to the same method?

Comment: I've double and triple checked and even re-written the code again to make sure I'm not copying anything that might make it use the same method.  It's not.  I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some sort of limitation I was hitting that I didn't know about.  Thanks.